# Questions about create table and transaction in sqlite3 of python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm learning to use sqlite in python by sqlite3.

The SQL operations like insert, update support support transaction and the commit() should be called before close the connection, or nothing would change in the database. However, the 'create table' do not support transaction, or the create table is auto committed. For example,

```
con.execute('create table xxx (xxxx)')
```

the table would be created instantly. What's more, if we execute an insert statement before creating table, without commit(). Then execute create table, the insert would be committed, as well as the 'create table'.

I found nothing mentioned about such behavior in document https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-types ,https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id3 or https://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html.

My question is:
1. Is there any other operations behave like this?
2. What does other DBMS behave?
3. Is there any specification about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour comes neither from SQLite (commands like CREATE TABLE work perfectly well inside transactions) nor from Python; it's the Python `sqlite3` module that tries to be clever and inserts automatic transactions at some places.

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions), but the reasons given are rather flimsy:

> There are two reasons for doing that. The first is that some of these commands don’t work within transactions.

If the module wouldn't automatically start transactions, it would not be required to close them before those commands.

> The other reason is that sqlite3 needs to keep track of the transaction state (if a transaction is active or not).

If the module wouldn't automatically start transaction, it would not need to keep track of the transaction state

Please note that the detection of DML statements does not work correctly in all cases.

I'd recommend to disable all this craziness by clearing `isolation_level`.

Comment: Same thing with the cursor stuff. Getting a `cursor` after opening the file and sticking with that forever removes overhead with no downsides.

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in the past years.

> Changed in version 3.6: sqlite3 used to implicitly commit an open transaction before DDL statements. This is no longer the case.

Let's have the following example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
import sys

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE friends(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO friends(name) VALUES ('Tom')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO friends(name) VALUES ('Rebecca')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO friends(name) VALUES ('Jim')")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE temp(int id)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO friends(nam) VALUES ('Robert')")

    con.commit()

except sqlite3.Error as e:

    if con:
        con.rollback()

    print(f'Error {e.args[0]}:')
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

There is an error in the last `INSERT` statement; the column name is wrong.
The `friends` table is created, the rows are not inserted, and the `temp`
table is not created. So the DDL `CREATE TABLE` no longer commits an open
transaction.

Why was `friends` table created, though? It is because Python sliqte3 module
starts a new transaction only for DML statements (i.e. INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE).