# Create Table with deferred foreign key referencing each other

Tags: sqlite, transactions, foreign-keys

I'm new to sqlite and sql in gerneral so I don't know if my approach is reasonable.

I want to model inventory items that can be created, lent, returned and discarded.

I want to model this using two tables, one for items, containing an id, a name and a reference to the last transaction (created, lent, returned, ...) and a table of transactions containing an id transaction type, date, and a reference to the item.

Since creating only one table leaves the database in an inconsitent state with one table referencing a non existant table I thought of using a transaction to crate both tables at once, and defining the foreign keys as deferrable. Creation of a new item would have to be done together in one transaction with creating a "created" event to leave the database in a consistent state.

The following code gives me the error `Query Error: not an error Unable to execute multiple statements at a time` in sqliteman on linux.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

begin transaction;
create table items (
id  integer primary key,
name char(30),
foreign key (last_transaction) references transactions(transaction_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

create table transactions(
transaction_id integer primary key,
text char(100)
foreign key (item) references items(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
commit transaction;
```

Does my approach make sense at all?
If yes, why does the code not work? (Did I make a mistake somewhere, or is what I'm trying impossible in mysql?)

Note: simply creating the tables in one transaction without the foreign key constraints gives the same error. (Could this be a similar Problem to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760997/questions-about-create-table-and-transaction-in-sqlite3-of-python))

Comment: Execute the statements one at a time. (This is no problem, even with transactions.) And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545189/sqlite-foreign-key

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, gave better error messages then. Also I need to create the first table and then create the second one and then add the foreign key to the first one. So I don't reference a non existant column but it works now.